# Copy and Paste Text into certian spot and lines

Tags: json, copy, paste, txt

so i have this .json file and a lot of text i need to put in there
Now i dont want to select everything and paste it one by one to its destination

So for example i have "" and i want paste my text to make it

"paste1"
"paste2"
"paste3"

How would i be able to copy my stuff from the txt, into the .jsons by making every line as seperate line, but keeping it in the same format at the same destination for that line?
Like how can i paste stuff between the "" but every paste would end up in a different line?

Hope someone could help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the txt file into a variable which will store the file data in it.
Then you would have to split the data at every new line which will return an array of data that you can manipulate to your liking.

Here's a sample of part of the code you might write using *Javascript*:

```
//data is the variable we have stored our txt file info in
let arr = data.split("\n") // <-- splitting the data which returns an array which we store in a variable called "arr"
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  arr[i] = "\""+arr[i]+"\"" //arr[i] is the value at every line and we are surrounding it with quotation marks
}
```

You can of course manipulate the data in whatever way you want and after that you would save the data in any format you'd like.

Comment: I am actually not good at programming, its just a simple list basically for a game, any chance i can send u the files and you could take a quick look?

Comment: @Spyr0 this isn't really the place but share a drive link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10T4nJeDM2XnpUDP3JtpmrihRJQvbO_--?usp=sharing

So i want to have the stuff from the spawncodes.txt in the economy one
{"tradeable-code" : "", "base-purchase-price" : "-1", "base-sell-price" : "-1", "delta-price" : "-1.0", "can-be-purchased" : "default"}, into the first "" and each one has to be a different line, like has to be in its own tradable code thingie

Comment: @Spyr0 So basically **05_Teeth_Necklace** becomes _{"tradeable-code" : "05_Teeth_Necklace", "base-purchase-price" : "-1", "base-sell-price" : "-1", "delta-price" : "-1.0", "can-be-purchased" : "default"}_. P.S: They are all in **A_0_Armory**, should the rest(**A_0_BoatShop**, **A_0_Mechanic**, ...) be empty

Comment: Yes correct, i couldnt edit my post anymore, yes the rest can stay empty

Comment: @Spyr0 we.tl/t-O5cn8Q8Xuw

Comment: Awesome, your the best, thank you very much!

Comment: @Spyr0 No prob, glad i can help. P.S: the answer should be accepted if it is correct